# Генерация рандомных чисел в C++

Tags: c++, c++11

Здорова ребята.Я по поводу генерации рандомно случайных чисел.Мой вопрос заключается в этом:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<random>

using namespace std;

default_random_engine numbers;
uniform_int_distribution<int>distribution(0,100)

int main()
{
    int arr[10]
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = distribution(numbers)
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << "\t";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

вроде бы все норм он у меня выводит рандомные числа, но есть одна проблема.Он у меня каждый раз выводит одинаковые числа, например при первой компиляции он у меня выводил допустим 22 13 99 45 23 66 90 91 9 2,при второй компиляции тоже выводит те же самые числа 22 13 99 45 23 66 90 91 9 2.Как это исправить?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37195821/rand-and-srand-functions-in-c

Comment: Спасибо, надо было прочтать хорошенько мануал по ходу

Comment: С минимальными изменениями -- добавьте `numbers.seed(time(0));` в начало main

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Одни и те же числа выводятся так как используется одно и то же начальное состояние движка. Вместо этого следует инициализировать его каждый раз новым затравочным значением:

```
::std::random_device device{};
::std::default_random_engine engine{device()};
```